# Consulta com relacionamento Muitos para Muitos Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Sou novo com Entity Framework e Linq, então minha dúvida pode ser muito simples, mas está quebrando minha cabeça.

Possuo duas entidades:

```
public class Fornecedor
    {
        public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Municipio> Municipios { get; set; }
    }


public class Municipio
    {
        public int MunicipioId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }   
    }
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta para retornar todos os fornecedores que atendem um determinado município.
Vou passar como parâmetro o nome do município, ex. são paulo, e preciso receber uma listagem com todos os fornecedores que atendem este município.

Espero ter sido claro.

Obrigado,
Alexandre Previatti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesse caso, o melhor seria obter a lista de fornecedores pelo município, desta forma:

```
var municipios= db.Municipio.Where(m => m.Nome == nome).ToList();
```

Se a consulta retornar apenas um município, ou você quiser retornar um município apenas, pode usar o `.FirstOrDefault()`, desta forma:

```
 var municipio= db.Municipio.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Nome == nome);
```

Para acessar os fornecedores basta acessar a lista de fornecedores do município.

```
municipio.Fonecedores
```

Pode usar o `.Select()` para obter somente a lista também, desta forma:

```
var fornecedores= db.Municipio.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Nome == nome).Select(m => m.Fornecedores);
```

> Lembrando que `db` é seu contexto do banco de dados.

**Edição**

Como lembrado pelo [@JamesTK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/25712/jamestk) nos comentários, vale ressaltar alguns pontos:

- Se o [Lazy Loading](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/aspnet/lazy-load-quando-usar.html) estiver desabilitado, você deverá acrescentar o `.Include()` em seu código.
  ex: `var municipio= db.Municipio.Include(m => m.Fornecedores).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Nome == nome);`
- Você também poderia buscar pelos funcionários, ficaria algo como isso:
  `db.Funcionarios.Where(f => f.Municipios.Any(m => m.Nome == "Sao Paulo"))`

Comment: Gostaria só de lembrar que se o Lazy Loading estiver desabilitado será necessário fazer o Include de Fornecedores.

Comment: Que apesar de `f => f` lembrar de `Fornecedor`, não é.  Nesse caso faz referência direta ainda a `Municipio` e que então poderia ser qualquer coisa, ckmo `x => x`. No exemplo dele a consulta é por meio do Nome do Município.

Comment: Último comentário. Poderia ser por meio de `Funcionarios` também: `db.Funcionarios.Where(x => x.Municipios.Any(m => m.Id == 1))`.

Comment: @JamesTK Realizei as edições com base nos comentários. Obrigado por lembrar.

Comment: @Randrade Obrigado pela resposta, foi muito útil. Caso eu tivesse mais uma entidade, por ex. Servico, onde quisesse buscar os fornecedores que prestam um determinado tipo de serviço em uma determinada cidade?? neste caso, teria dois relacionamentos muitos para muitos.

Comment: @AlexandrePreviatti Você pode colocar mais de um parâmetro dentro do `.Where()`, por exemplo: `.Where(x => x.Nome == 'Sao Paulo' && x.Servico.Nome == 'Servico1')`. Algo como isso, dependendo de seu relacionamento